# How do I change ttk.LabelFrame's blue header label to black in python's tkinter 8.5

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using tkinter 8.5 and python 3.3 on a Windows 7 machine.

The code below renders the Labelframe's header in a blue font color.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Why is this blue?")
lf.pack()

label = ttk.Label(lf, text="label")
label.pack()
```

I tried fixing this by adding a ttk.Style(), but got an unexpected display:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabelframe.Label', font='arial 14 bold')

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Now it's black, but w/ a bizarre display"
                    " and no etched frame.", style='TLabelframe.Label')
lf.pack()

label = ttk.Label(lf, text="label")
label.pack()
```

Is there a way to get a ttk.LabelFrame header to appear black in color w/o weird side effects?

Comment: Can you post a complete example? If you just take this code plus `root.mainloop()` does it demonstrate the problem for you (it doesn't for me…), or do you need more than that?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, that was the complete example. I forgot the `root.mainloop()`, but that doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Windows defaults ttk.Labelframe headers to this blue color. Not sure why.

[image: Mac and Linux default to black, while Windows defaults to blue.]

I found a solution by creating a ttk.Label and passing that as ttk.Labelframe's labelwidget argument. This might be more of a workaround, though. In any event, the code below displays the header text in black on my Windows 7 machine.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

l = ttk.Label(text="Not blue anymore")

lf = ttk.Labelframe(root, labelwidget=l)
lf.pack()

label = ttk.Label(lf, text="label")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be changed using the foreground property `tk.LabelFrame(window, foreground='red')`

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but for those just finding it: the question was regarding ttk.Labelframe, not tk.LabelFrame. The former does not have a foreground option, and displays black by default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `style='TLabelframe.Label'` from the `ttk.LabelFrame` options.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabelframe.Label', font='arial 14 bold')

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Now it's black, but w/ a bizarre display"
                    " and no etched frame.")
lf.pack()

label = ttk.Label(lf, text="label")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3.7.3 and tkinter 8.6.

Answer (score 0):

First define your `ttk` style:

```
frame_label = ttk.Style()
frame_label.configure('Frame.TLabel', 
                       foreground = "black", # fontcolor
                       font=("Sans-serif",11)
                       )
```

Then apply this to your frame text, e.g. "Why is this blue?":

```
lbl = ttk.Label(text = "Why is this blue?", style='Frame.TLabel')
label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root,
                             labelwidget=lbl
                              )
```