# How do I change ttk.LabelFrame's header label to blue in python's tkinter on Linux?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the label text to be blue, as it is by default on Windows.

I'm following a tutorial on Python and Tkinter that was written for Windows, but I'm doing it on Linux (Python 3.5.1 on xubuntu 16.04.5).  Right now I'm puzzled by the fact that all the LabelFrame examples in the book have a blue  header label, but when I run their code, my header labels are black.

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25002373/1422472) that  blue is default in Windows.  I'd like to see the same effect in Linux.  However, I have been unable to reverse the suggestions there.  For instance, "foreground" does not appear to be an option for ttk.LabelFrame(), and I also don't know how to make the text of a Label to be blue to use it as the labelwidget option.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("My question")

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Why is this not blue?")
lf.pack()

label = ttk.Label(lf, text="frame contents can remain black or whatever.")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("My question")
lw = Label(root,  text="This is blue now", fg="blue")
lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root,labelwidget=lw)
lf.pack()
label = ttk.Label(lf, text="frame contents can remain black or whatever.")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer but didn't notice you're using LabelFrame instead of Label.

As the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm) says, you need to pass an `options` argument to your `LabelFrame` class.

Try this:

```
lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, fg='blue', text="Now it should be blue")
```

Comment: When I try that, I get  tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-options"

Comment: @ForDummies then try passing fg=blue . It’s really simple and it doesn’t require adding any lines of code

Comment: It's simple all right, but still doesn't work: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fg" ---- perhaps because of the version of Python?